# Best time to buy used (wind-)surfing equipment

Tags: gear, surfing, windsurfing

I am wondering if there is a best time to buy used surfing equipment. Is there any time when the offered variety will be greatest or when the prices will be lowest? Would that be just after season or at the start?

Will this differ for windsurfing, kitesurfing and waveriding?

Comment: Usually prices for outdoor gear like this get cheaper in the winter, or right before the release of new season products.

Comment: i would add that usually with outdoor gear it is at the end of the season that you will start to see sales followed by further sales off season and then full out clearance prices prior to the new season start.  Also most gear that doesn't go on sale like rock climbing "cams" will go on sale when a new model is replacing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much all my wind surfing equipment is used (I'm still just getting into it) and I've discovered that the best time to buy windsurfing equipment is at the beginning of summer, for a a couple of reasons:

1. People who buy *new* are getting their new stuff for the year and
   want to sell off their old stuff to make room in their garage, or
   they need the extra money to afford the newer stuff.
2. The kids have gone to University/moved out on their own, and their
   parents want to get rid of all the junk they left behind (This is exactly how I scored 4 boards, 5 sails, 2 masts and 5 booms, plus all the mast bases, etc. all for $200).

Comment: +1 for a season based answer, seasons are different by hemisphere.